# Backbone model URL propertry is set but still getting error that it mut be specified

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone, and I've been fairly successful with model and view implementation. Now I am looking into building a RESTful back-end to experiment with this aspect of backbone. So, I've created this simple client to test requests and responses. However, I keep receiving this error:
**A "url" property or function must be specified**

Seems to me a client problem, but perhaps it is on the server side. Can anyone explain why I might be getting this error, of if this setup is wrong, why?

```
var m_Blog = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        url:'/lib',
        title: null,
        date: null,
        content: null,
        keywords: null,
    }
});

var a = new m_Blog({title:'t', date:'d', content:'c', keywords:'w'});

a.save({
       success: function(model, response) {
           alert('Success' + response.getResponseHeader());
       },
       fail: function(model, response) {
           alert('Fail' + response.getResponseHeader());
       }
});
```

I've also tried a simple save call since, I'm really not sure yet if the above works:

```
a.save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the attribute is actually called "urlRoot". Have you tried changing your defaults to this?

```
defaults: {
    urlRoot:'/lib',
    title: null,
    date: null,
    content: null,
    keywords: null,
}
```

url is the function name on the model to get the urlRoot (ie. model.url()).

If that doesn't work, you could also try setting the urlRoot this way although I'm pretty sure it's doing the same thing as above :-).

```
var m_Blog = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: null,
        date: null,
        content: null,
        keywords: null,
    },

    urlRoot: '/lib'
});
```

Comment: I did try both url and urlRoot, but it doesn't work. However, I did get past that error by moving the url outside of the defaults, so thanks. I would still like to know why the default url doesn't work. I even tried passing the url in the constructor, which didn't work, and that's probably why I didn't even think of moving it out of the default.

Comment: That makes sense when I think about. Setting the defaults property just sets the model.attributes object with some default values. urlRoot would be a completely separate attribute on the model (so, model.url) rather than in it's attributes. Glad I could help!